# A special error message after installing Kile on WSL, for LaTeX

Tags: windows, linux, kile

I use WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux).

I have tried to install Kile for LaTeX by

```
sudo apt-get install kile
```

As soon as I did, i wanted to open Kile by:

```
kile&
```

And I had the following error message:

```
kile&
[2] 5625
name@DESKTOP-DSIVPPD:~$ QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-name'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:0.0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Could you help me to solve that problem?

Comment: wsl by default doesn't come with X you need to install an X server on your display but that's off topic here

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about WSL and not about LaTeX.